# How to share a file between Android and desktop operating system?

Tags: android, sharing

My invoicing application can generate a csv file.

My sales person has an android based cell phone.

I intend to write an application for his cell phone which will allow him to filter contents of the csv file.

I will generate a new csv file daily since new transactions occur every day.

The app in the cell phone must be able to check for and update itself with the new csv file whenever it is able to get internet connection. Internet connection will not be present at all times on the cell phone.

My question is where should this new csv file be placed so that it can be shared?

(PS: I am using Mac OS but avoided mentioning it in the title so as not let non-Mac users skip reading the question. My assumption is OS-independent solution exist)

Comment: Create a web service that the salesperson will access from his phone (running your app) to retrieve the CSV file

Comment: Alternatively, use some sort of file upload service which has an API, such as Dropbox, and have your code upload your file, and the code on your phone retrieve it every day.

Answer (score 0):

The phone app can have an ajax function to poll the web service and update the file if it is newer than the one it has.